# Why can browser extensions use "fetch" without cross-origin permissions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, fetch, firefox-addon-webextensions

When `XMLHttpRequest` is being used to do cross-origin requests, permissions are required via `manifest.json`, as stated here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/xhr

But when using `fetch`, it doesn't need it and can requests to all ressources.

What makes `fetch` different than `XMLHttpRequest` that it works without persmissions? Or is that just bug?

Comment: Can't reproduce. There must be something else in your case.

Comment: *"But when using fetch, it doesn't need it and can requests to all ressources."* - can you post request logs and maybe some example code of what you're doing? Preferably the same thing with XHR and fetch side by side.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'll post them asap. Just making sure I did nothing wrong.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/timche/5b83406843b79f1fb6c7f5894acaafb5 this is what I've tried out. I actually thought that XMLHttpRequest would be blocked due to cross-origin as stated in the documentation above, but it didn't. So why can data be fetched without permissions at all?